# How to have a bootstrap class button link to an external site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, hyperlink, external

I m having problem with a button that i created and trying to link to an external website. my code is

```
<div id="home-btn" class="animated zoomIn">
   <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white smooth-scroll"  
   href="http://www.yumpu.com/fr/embed/view/OPR2Gbw5Ml83hkp4" target="_blank" 
   role="button"  title="Magazine Carrefour Floride en ligne">Clicquez ici pour 
   lire le Magazine en Ligne</a>
   </div>
```

I tried to place the href else where but same thing will not work. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your html code seems to be fine, making a little test worked for me, perhaps your issue is in styles, check if you accidentally disabled the link functionality in one of the css classes: class="animated zoomIn" or class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white smooth-scroll", hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks Eddy for your help i just remove the smooth-scroll and it now works! Happy 4th of July!

Answer (score 0):

Adding role of button to the link is what has prevented the default behaviours. Either you remove the `role` attributes or modify your code to look something light this;

```
<div id="home-btn" class="animated zoomIn">
    <a href="http://www.yumpu.com/fr/embed/view/OPR2Gbw5Ml83hkp4" target="_blank">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white smooth-scroll"  type="button" title="Magazine Carrefour Floride en ligne">Clicquez ici pour lire le Magazine en Ligne.   <button> 
    </a>
```

Comment: Thanks! it work i just got rid of smooth-scroll et voila!!! thank you Hazelcodes have a nice 4th of July!

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned the code, and added btn-default.
If you want to change color just choose from these:

```
.btn
.btn-default
.btn-primary
.btn-success
.btn-info
.btn-warning
.btn-danger
.btn-link
```

you code:

```
<div id="home-btn" class="animated zoomIn">
  <a class="btn  btn-default btn-lg btn-general btn-white smooth-scroll" 
    href="http://www.yumpu.com/fr/embed/view/OPR2Gbw5Ml83hkp4" target="_blank"> 
    Clicquez ici pour ire le Magazine en Ligne
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks DevAymen  tried the code but still not work this way. we only had to remove the smoot-scrool! Thanks for helping me Happy 4th of July!